# Unable to connect to Microsoft SQL server from RStudio

Tags: windows, windows-8, sql-server, r, rstudio

The aim is to read data from a Microsoft SQL server in RStudio. I am on Windows. So I have:

1. Installed RODBC package;
2. Created ODBC DSN pointing to the SQL server I need to read data from.

I can successfully connect to the server and read data through the standart R on Windows (RGUI). I can define connection both with `odbcConnect()` or `odbcDriverConnect()` without any errors. For example:

```
> con <- odbcConnect("SQLB")
> as.list(odbcGetInfo(con))
$DBMS_Name
[1] "Microsoft SQL Server"

$DBMS_Ver
[1] "09.00.5000"

$Driver_ODBC_Ver
[1] "03.52"

$Data_Source_Name
[1] "SQLB"

$Driver_Name
[1] "SQLSRV32.DLL"

$Driver_Ver
[1] "06.03.9600"

$ODBC_Ver
[1] "03.80.0000"

$Server_Name
[1] "SQLB\\SQLB"
```

If I do the same in RStudio it always fails with error messages:

```
> con <- odbcConnect("SQLB")
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=SQLB") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=SQLB") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 67, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
3: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=SQLB") : ODBC connection failed
```

It takes on average 16.5 seconds to return the error message.

```
> require(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(odbcConnect("SQLB"), times = 10L)
Unit: seconds
                expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 odbcConnect("SQLB") 16.52802 16.52953 16.53059 16.5298 16.53141 16.53639    10
There were 30 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

I have tried other drivers but the situation is the same - they all work for R but they fail for RStudio. I can not understand why it works in R but it does not work in RStudio. Please ask if more details should be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install R and RStudio as administrator in `C:\Program Files\`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was valid for one month. It started to fail both for R and RStudio. Probably there were some security policy changes I was not aware of.

---

The solution is pretty unusual. Previously my RStudio installation was in

```
C:\Softs\RStudio\bin
```

I made a new installation of RStudio in

```
C:\Users\MLiberts\Documents\RStudio-1.0.44\bin
```

and the problem is gone. Keep in mind that I am still using the old settings of the RStudio as they are stored in

```
C:\Users\MLiberts\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop
```

and I have not changed them.

So it seems that Windows 8 is implying different permissions on executable files depending the location they are stored in. I have full permissions on `C:\Users\MLiberts\Documents` but I do not have full permissions on `C:\Softs` however I can read and write there.

```
C:\Softs\RStudio>icacls bin
bin BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

C:\Users\MLiberts\Documents\RStudio-1.0.44>icacls bin
bin NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    CSPDOM\mliberts:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```